# How to install development version of Apache Marmotta

Tags: git, apache, maven, apache-marmotta

I want to develop a webapp with [Apache Marmotta](http://marmotta.apache.org/kiwi/geosparql.html). The current release `3.3` (released in 2014) does not provide GeoSPARQL functionalities, [which seems to be present in the 3.4 version](http://marmotta.apache.org/kiwi/geosparql.html). I saw at least one instance of a `3.4.0-SNAPSHOT` online ([here](http://linkeddata.ec/marmotta/core/admin/system.html)). Nevertheless, I couldn't find its installation files. I tried to clone and install the [git repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/marmotta.git) with maven, but it keeps installing version `3.3`.

Comment: The latest development on that repository seems to happen in `develop` branch, so make sure that after you clone you do `git checkout develop`

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Apache Marmotta 3.4.0 will not support GeoSPARQL because it forces users to install PostGIS and works only PostgreSQL; there is also a change in the schema of the DB. Until there is a new approach I think it won't be released. However, you can try it yourself. Just clone the branch `MARMOTTA-584`, which has this functionality.

Clone:

```
git clone -b MARMOTTA-584 https://github.com/apache/marmotta
```

cd to marmotta folder and build it:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Deploy the war in Apache Tomcat 7 and there you go; btw you need to use PostgreSQL and install PostGIS.

Comment: Is this official? From this page, it seems they might actually include it with the next release (3.4): http://marmotta.apache.org/kiwi/geosparql.html

Comment: AFAK, I worked on it as part of GSOC 2015. The documentation also says this: _Warning! Because some portability issues, GeoSPARQL support has not been shipped as part of any public release. We expect to manage to solve it in a future release. In the meantime, you need to build branch MARMOTTA-584 manually from the source code._ In [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MARMOTTA-584?jql=project%20%3D%20MARMOTTA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22geosparql%22) the release cycle for GeoSPARQL has been moved to version 3.5.0.